# Incompatible types - Required: android.net.Uri, found: int

Tags: android

I can't compile the following code:

```
public long create (Context mContext, ContentValues rights)
{
    Long id;
    Uri mNewOwner = mContext.getContentResolver().insert( 
        this.getMyUri(),
        rights);
    id = ContentUris.parseId(mNewOwner);
    this.setID(id);
    this.setMyUri(ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id));

    return id;
}

public void update(Context mContext)
{
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_RIGHTS_POWER, this.getRightPower());
    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_RIGHTS_EVENT, this.getRightEvent());
    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_RIGHTS_RULE, this.getRightRule());
    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_RIGHTS_USER, this.getRightUser());
    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_RIGHTS_GAME, this.getRightGame());
    updatedValues.put(Game2user.FIELD_IS_PLAYER, this.getIsPlayer());
    Uri mUpdatedObject = mContext.getContentResolver().update(
            this.getMyUri(),
            updatedValues,null,null);
}
```

Uri mUpdatedObject gives me an error `Incompatible types - Required: android.net.Uri, found: int.` . I don't understand why/where it sees an int since getMyUri returns an Uri...

```
public Uri getMyUri() {
    return myUri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the method that is ultimately called is the update(Uri, ContentValues, String, String[]) which returns an int that represents the number of rows updated. Your method is passed as an argument inside the update method.